# Why does JavaMail BodyPart.getInputStream() return an empty stream when using IMAP, but not when using POP3?

Tags: java, inputstream, imap, pop3, jakarta-mail

I have a `javax.mail` application that parses through emails and gets the `InputStream` for all `application/*` attachments:

```
private DataInputStream getAttachmentStream(Message message) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) message.getContent();

        for (int p = 0; p < mp.getCount(); p++) {
            BodyPart part = mp.getBodyPart(p);

            if (part.getContentType().toLowerCase().startsWith("application")) {
                InputStream is = part.getInputStream();

                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

                App.logger.info("Found attachment."");
                return dis;
            }
        }
    }

    App.logger.warn("No attachment found.");
    return null;
}
```

My problem is that even for emails that have an attachment, the resultant `DataInputStream` is empty. I've stepped through in the debugger, and `part` is definitely the correct `Message` part with the attachment.

**I switched the protocol of my code that checks the email address to use POP3 instead of IMAP, and this code magically worked. Can anyone explain why this code works for POP3 and not for IMAP?**

Comment: did you step into the `getInputStream()` call to see what it does?

Comment: No I haven't. I'll try that; thanks!

Comment: I was able to get my code to work simply by switching to POP3 instead of IMAP. Can anyone explain why this didn't work in IMAP?

Comment: IMAP permits javamail to use a much lazier form of message retrieval, POP forces clients to fetch all or nothing (aaaaalmost). It sounds as if javamail hasn't fetched the bits you expect to use yet.

Comment: @arnt Thanks! That sounds like it's the case; any links to some docs or blog posts to back that up? (You could post that as answer, then.) :)

Comment: I don't particularly care to back it up. I haven't seen much of the code, and not any protocol traces either, so what I'm doing is guessing. If you want to check the guess, have a look at your IMAP protocol trace and see if it's downloading much less than via POP and retrieving items like ENVELOPE, BODY or BODYSTRUCTURE instead of the entire message bodies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been some time since this thread was opened, but I think the problem described in here was due to bugs in partial fetch implementation of IMAP server. As described in this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#fetch and in these notes https://javamail.java.net/docs/NOTES.txt . There is a workaround to solve it, add the following property:

> props.setProperty("mail.imap.partialfetch", "false");