# Convert a JavaMail attachment into blob?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

How do I use JavaMail to convert a file attached to an email into a persistable `java.sql.blob`? In my code attempt below, the Eclipse debugger and the `SYSO` commands identify that there is indeed an `xml` attachment which does get cast as an `InputStream`, but yet the `blob` and `content` variables remain empty despite the code's attempts to transfer the `InputStream` into them.

What can I change to correctly transfer the `InputStream` into `blob` format?

```
        for(int y=1;y<=msg_count;y++){
            Message msg = inbox.getMessage(y);
            System.out.println("msg# is: "+y);
            Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
            for (Address address : in) {System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());}
            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
            if(msg.getContent() instanceof String){System.out.println("msg.getContent()(String!) is: "+msg.getContent());}
            if(msg.getContent() instanceof Multipart){
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
                for(int a=0;a<mp.getCount();a++){
                    BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(a);
                    System.out.println("a, FILENAME (Multipart!) are: " +a+", "+ bp.getFileName());
                    System.out.println("a, CONTENTTYPE (Multipart!) are: "+a+", "+bp.getContentType());
                    if(bp.getFileName()!=null){
                        if(bp.getFileName().endsWith(".xml")){
                            System.out.println("a, CONTENT, class.name (Multipart!) are: " +a+", "+ bp.getContent()+", "+bp.getClass().getName());
                            if(bp.getContent() instanceof InputStream){
                                InputStream myis = (InputStream)bp.getContent();
                                DocumentPreImport docpre = new DocumentPreImport();
                                SomeDocument cd = mf.unmarshal(new StreamSource(myis), schemaFile);
                                docpre.setDocTitle(cd.getTitle());
                                List<IItempId> ids = cd.getTemplateId();
                                for(int u=0;u<ids.size();u++){docpre.setDocTemplateId(ids.get(0).getRoot());}
                                PatientRole pr = cd.getRecordTarget().get(0).getPatientRole();
                                docpre.setPatientRoleRoot(pr.getId().get(0).getRoot());
                                docpre.setPatientRoleExtension(pr.getId().get(0).getExtension());
                                Blob blob = null;
                                byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(myis);
                                try {
                                    blob = new SerialBlob(content);
                                    docpre.setContent(blob);
                                } 
                                catch (SerialException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                                catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                                docpre.setSourceEmailAddress(msg.getFrom()[0].toString());
                                docpre.setMsgSentDate(msg.getSentDate().toString());
                                docpre.setMsgSubject(msg.getSubject());
                                docpre.setImported(false);
                                this.clinicService.saveDocPreImport(docpre);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          msg.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);//flags this message as deleted, which does not yet fully expunge it from server
        }
        inbox.close(true);//expunges from server all the messages which were flagged as deleted. this line is required to actually delete.
```

### Update

I don't think this question is a duplicate.  The other question is specific to `InputStream`, while this question is general to `JavaMail` attachments.

Comment: @EJP this question is not a duplicate.  Please remove your flag.  The other question is specific to inputstream.  This question is general to JavaMail attachments.  Two very different questions.  Please reply with confirmation that you have removed your flag accordingly.  And please answer the question if you have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not when converting, at least I've tested the following code and it works fine for me:

```
BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
InputStream stream = (InputStream)bp.getInputStream();
byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream); //content.length shows correct length
Blob blob = null;
blob = new SerialBlob(content); // blob.length() shows correct length
```

Take a look at: [Why does JavaMail BodyPart.getInputStream() return an empty stream when using IMAP, but not when using POP3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812757/why-does-javamail-bodypart-getinputstream-return-an-empty-stream-when-using-im)

If you are really using IMAP, try adding the following property:
`props.setProperty("mail.imap.partialfetch", "false");`

Comment: This does not answer my question. It just states that you have something working in your configuration without explaining what makes your configuration different than mine. I tried `props.setProperty("mail.imap.partialfetch", "false");` and changed `bp.getContent()` to `bp.getInputStream()`. The debugger all along has been saying that the inputstream has stuff in it, so this is a different problem than the link you gave. I am grateful that you spent time looking into this. Thank you. But please understand that I end up continually asking new questions if the root of a question is not addressed